# Navigation bar - why do I get borders?

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar, border, autolayout

I have searched but could not find a solution for this...
I have a view controller in storyboard, and I want to add a navigation/toolbar bar under the status bar with a cancel button. I can place a navigation bar using constraints, but I get unwanted borders around the navigation bar. How do I get rid of these?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I had customized the appearance of UINavigationBar for iOS 6 and forgotten to disable that code.